# How to delete items that exist in one table from another?

Tags: sql

I have tables A and B. Items of table B might exist also in table A, and I want to delete those items. What would the SQL statements to do this look like?

Comment: it varies depending on your database server platform. What are you using? Mysql? SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

this is an option

```
delete from a
where a.key in (select key from b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
DELETE a
WHERE a.some_field IN (SELECT some_field FROM b)
```

or

```
DELETE A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.field1 = a.field2)
```

Depending on your database, you may find one works particularly better than the other.  IIRC Oracle tends to prefer WHERE EXISTS to IN but this can depend on a number of factors.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
DELETE 
FROM TableA as A 
WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT ID 
               FROM TableB AS B 
               WHERE [your condition here])
```

Answer (score 2):

In certain DBs the rather exotic looking DELETE FROM FROM is *very* efficient

```
delete from foo from foo as f
where exists 
(
  select 1 from bar as b  where b.field = f.field
)
```

Comment: Which DB systems? What does it do?

Comment: Ah, I see. That's equivalent to the UPDATE FROM syntax on SQL Server.

Comment: Definitely worked on MSSQL 2K and I think 2K5 - googling "delete from from" yields some interesting results

Comment: +1 ... never heard of DELETE FROM FROM before, but I've definitely had cases where I could have used it. Now I know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables use InnoDB, the easiest way would be to setup table A with [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) from table B, and use ON DELETE CASCADE. That way no code changes are necessary, and the integrity of your database is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This is allowed according to the standard.

```
delete a from a join b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this one worked for me on a similar problem I encountered today.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete a
--select a.*
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.someid = b.someid
```

Make sure that you run the select part first to ensure that you are getting the records you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM FIRST_TABLE FT
WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM SECOND_TABLE ST
            WHERE ST.PRIMARY_KEY = FT.PRIMARY_KEY
            );
```